# Are non-FDA approved vaccines good for entering the US?

Tags: usa, covid-19, vaccinations

[This page](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/proof-of-vaccination.html#covid-vaccines) of the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention (CDC) website states that all non-citizen, nonimmigrant traveling to the US must present proof of a full COVID-19 vaccination, and proceeds to list the US Food and Drugs Administration (FDA) approved vaccines (Pfizer-BioNTech, Moderna, Novavax and Johnson & Johnson’s Janssen), as well as the vaccines listed for emergency use by the World Health Organization (WHO) that are not FDA-approved, which includes the Sinovac vaccine (the one I received).

My question then is: **are these non-FDA approved vaccines accepted to enter the US?**

I could not find this information in the CDC page, nor elsewhere, although the wording suggests they are: however, it seems wiser to me to confirm my interpretation before actually flying to the US... [This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/176612/approved-vaccine-doses-along-with-non-approved-vaccine-for-travel-to-us) is very similar, but asks about a vaccine that is not listed by the WHO, the Sputnik.

**Update:** I arrived in the US a few days ago, and was not even asked about my vaccinations; in fact, I was one of the few people in the airport using a mask...

Comment: I visited USA from UK recently, and not once was I asked for any vaccine paperwork.

Comment: @Stewart If your name was Novak, and you are a famous tennis player, then they most likely would have checked :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**This requirement was dropped [as expected](https://www.cdc.gov/quarantine/order-safe-travel.html?CDC_AA_refVal=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cdc.gov%2Fcoronavirus%2F2019-ncov%2Ftravelers%2Fproof-of-vaccination.html):**

> CDC’s Amended Order Implementing Presidential Proclamation on Safe Resumption of Global Travel During the COVID-19 Pandemic ceased to be in effect as of 12:01 a.m. EDT on May 12, 2023.  An announcement of the termination of this Amended Order has been published in the Federal Register.

> This means that as of 12:01 a.m. EDT on May 12, 2023, noncitizen nonimmigrant air passengers no longer need to show proof of being fully vaccinated with an accepted COVID-19 vaccine to board a flight to the United States.

---

**HISTORICAL ANSWER**

The CDC is the US government agency that specifies which vaccines are acceptable for entry into the US.  The CDC page you link to says

> If you are a noncitizen nonimmigrant and are fully vaccinated, make sure your vaccine and proof of vaccination are acceptable to board a flight to the United States.

and then lists the following (which includes the Sinovac) as accepted vaccines:

> ### Accepted COVID-19 Vaccines
>
> **Vaccines Approved or Authorized by the U.S. Food and Drug Administration**
>
> - Janssen/J&J
> - Comirnaty (Pfizer-BioNTech)
> - Spikevax (Moderna)
> - Novavax
>
> **Vaccines Listed for Emergency Use (EUL) by the World Health Organization**
>
> - Janssen/J&J
> - Convidecia (CanSinoBIO)
> - Comirnaty (Pfizer-BioNTech)
> - Spikevax (Moderna)
> - Vaxzevria (AstraZeneca)
> - Covaxin
> - Covishield
> - BIBP/Sinopharm
> - CoronaVac (Sinovac)
> - Nuvaxovid (Novavax)
> - Covovax
>
> **Certain Clinical Trial Vaccines which Have Confirmed Efficacy**
>
> - Medicago

These are the vaccines accepted for travel to the United States.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I cannot believe I did not see the colossal "Accepted COVID-19 Vaccines" at the top of the table...

Answer (score 2):

Please note that [from May 11th 2023](https://www.forbes.com/sites/geoffwhitmore/2023/05/02/united-states-covid-19-travel-restrictions-to-be-lifted/), all Covid restrictions have been lifted to enter on the US, so you don't need to be vaccinated.